# Help for a question from a number theory book

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This excercise is from a number theory book

prove that if:

$a_sk^s+a_{s-1}k^{s-1}+...+a_0$

is a representation of $n$ to the base $k$, then $0<n \leq k^{s+1}-1$

The book gave the reader a hint in which it says to use the theorem:

if $x$ is any real number other than 1, then $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} x^j = \dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}$

I am very confused on where to start and how to even approach this problem. Help on where to start would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using an induction argument on this problem?

Comment: @Chris Would I set it up like this: Induction base step n=1: 0<1<k^s+1-1? I am not really sure what to do after or if I am doing it correctly.

Comment: Hint: $0\le a_j \le k-1$ for all $j$.

Comment: @Gary I still cant figure out how this can be applied to the problem.

Comment: Well, from what I told you, it follows that $$
0 \le a_s k^s  + a_{s - 1} k^{s - 1}  +  \ldots  + a_0  \le (k - 1)k^s  + (k - 1)k^{s - 1}  +  \ldots  + (k - 1) = (k - 1)(k^s  + k^{s - 1}  +  \ldots  + 1)
$$ Does this help?

Comment: It does thank you for all your help!